# О непреднамеренной двусмысленности

Tags: пунктуация, значение-слов, аббревиатуры

Очевидно, что не о заводе и не о членистоногих речь. Но не сразу... Как поступить при оформлении фраз, которые вызывают усмешку, а сообщают о событиях, в т. ч. трагических?

> ВАЗ будто под танк попал.
>
> Раки начнут откладывать деньги.